# how to use ActiveStorage to upload image to the backend and get the url for the image inclded in the response sent to the frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I am working on implementing a feature for adding products to the backend. I have successfully added the product to the backend, from the frontend, but I am having trouble sending image of the product with the product data. I am using ActiveStorage to upload the image.

### what i am trying:

- image is sent to the backend using FormData
  `const formData = new FormData(); formData.append("product[image]", e.target.image.files[0]))`
- installed ActiveStorage in the backend
- in the backend, I used has_one_attached :image in the product model,(I want to upload multiple images, but I am not sure how to do that so I am just trying to upload one image first)
- in the product controller, I added image to the product params

### what I am stuck on:

when the image is saved to the backend, I am not sure how to get the url for the image, so that I can send it to the frontend currently when products are sent to frontend, the image is not included in the response. I am not sure how to add the image to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [has_many_attached](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached) declaration to attach multiple images to the products:

## product.rb

```
has_many_attached :images
```

Here is how you can get the displayable URL for an image attached to a `product`:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_url(product.images.first)
```